# $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{Z}_2$ is generated by one element

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why does the group algebra $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{Z}_2$, which is of vector space dimension $2$, is generated as an algebra by just one element?

Comment: Write $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \langle{1, g\rangle}$ (multiplicatively). Then $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}_2]$ is generated as a vector space by $[1]$ and $[g]$ with $[g]^2 = [1]$.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}_2] = \{ a [g]+b [g^2], (a,b) \in \mathbb{C}\}$

Comment: I thought $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the same, just another notation, as $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, isn't it? So i am confused about $\mathbb{Z}_2=<1,g>$.

Comment: Maybe someone can tall me if it is the same group as I have thought or not? :)